# Select2 Dynamic elements not reacting to event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) which works great. However I am using below code to create new dynamic select2 drop down but they do not react/open when clicking on them.

```
var relationshipcounter = 0;

$('#AddMoreRelationships').click(function () {
    var $relationship = $('.relationship'); // div containing select2 dropdown
    var $clone = $relationship.eq(0).clone();
    $clone[0].id = 'id_' + ++relationshipcounter;
    $relationship.eq(-1).after($clone);

    $relationship.find('select').trigger('change'); // not working
});
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/pHSdP/133/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so issue is resolved, fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WrSxV/1/

```
// add another select2
var counter = 0;
$('#addmore').click(function(){
    var $relationship = $('.relationship');
    var $clone = $("#RelationshipType").clone();
    $clone[0].id = 'id_' + ++counter;
    $clone.show();
    $relationship.eq(-1).after($clone);
    $clone.select2({ "width" : "200px" });// convert normal select to select2

    //$('body').select2().on('change', 'select', function(){
      //  alert(this.id);
    //}).trigger('change');

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact problem and, of course, the first thing I tried was a deep copy with data:

```
el.clone(true,true);
```

Which did not work. Instead the best method I found was:

```
el=other_el.clone()_etc; // cloning the old row
el.find('.select2-container').remove();
el.find('select').select2({width: 268});
```

`el` in both of these snippets is the `div` row that contains the `select` and so the Select2 element.

Essentially what I do in the second snippet is remove the "old" select2 which will always have the class of `.select2-container` and then recreate it on all found `select` elements within my new row.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `clone` with the `true` argument to copy over events and data as well. Otherwise only the element gets cloned, not the events that are bound to it.

```
$relationship.eq(0).clone(true);
```

Docs:http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Thanks but it opens dropdown of first two/original ones not the clonned ones :(

Comment: @Dev01 Post the `change` event handler then. We can't figure out what the problem with your code is without seeing all of the relevant parts.

Comment: Yes. Try using `.clone(true)` instead of just `.clone()` - That should solve it.

Comment: There is no change event registered for it. When I click on clone, the drop down of first/orignal select is shown instead

Comment: Looks like the component is strictly binding to the first instance and does not support live instances (i.e. does not use .on(), .live() inside to accommodate future/cloned drop downs)

Comment: There is nothing wrong in *your* code. The plugin is just not built generically enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on` to bind dynamically inserted elements to events like

```
$('body').on('click','#AddMoreRelationships',function () {
});
```

Comment: You've got the correct function now, but you've got the wrong syntax; this is a static event handler, it won't react to dynamically added elements.

Comment: Would really appreciate if you can suggest changes required.. @AnthonyGrist

Comment: @Deadlock Start with the [API for `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and read, in particular, the parts about delegated events.

Comment: Thanks for reference @AnthonyGrist I had made changes in answer. Will it bind to dynamic inserted events now?

Answer (score 0):

After cloning your object you have to reassign event for em:

```
var $clone = $relationship.eq(0).clone();
$clone.on("click", function_name);
```